# How to put Arabic text in a txt file

Tags: python, notepad

I have been trying to put Arabic text in a `.txt` file and when do so using the code bellow I get this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: character maps to <undefined>`

code:

```
Log1 = open("File.txt", "a")
Log1.write("سلام")
Log1.close()
```

This question was asked in stack overflow many times but all of them has suggested using `utf-8` which will output `\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85` for this case, I was wondering if there is anyways to make the thing in the text file look like the `سلام` instead of `\xd8\xb3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85`.

Comment: What are you using to view the text file?

Comment: I am using Notepad

Comment: It appears that Notepad may have problems displaying non-ASCII data. This is not really a Python issue. I'll add Notepad to the tags

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly:

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'

with open(FILENAME, "w", encoding='utf-8') as data:
    data.write("سلام")
```

Then from a zsh shell:

```
cat foo.txt
سلام
```